# Space between Footnote marker and footnote text

Tags: footnotes

For my dissertation I need to put a space between the footnote marker and text. I don't know if there is package that could make this easier, or maybe add a modification to the following code:

Edit: I cleaned up the MWE.

```
%footnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \noindent\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark}\raggedright#1}
\makeatother
\setlength{\footnotesep}{24pt}
```

Below is the full MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=12pt,ignorehead,ignorefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[style=sbl,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,minnames=1,backend=biber,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter,doi=false,url=true]{biblatex}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%footnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \noindent\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark}\raggedright#1}
\makeatother
\setlength{\footnotesep}{24pt}

  
\begin{document}

This is a sample text with a sample footnote.\footnote{This is the footnote text. I would like a space between the footnote marker and the footnote text.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please remove unrelated package loading and configuration lines from your example.

Comment: why not use `.~\footnote{...}` ? (seems a strange requirement, to leave the marker hanging in free space, but thesis requirements are often strange...)

Comment: This creates a space in the main body of text. What I need is a space in the footnote area, between the number and the footnoted text.

Comment: For example ` \noindent\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark\enspace}\raggedright#1}` ?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, Simon! If you turn your comment into an answer I will be happy to give a check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some horizontal space after the marker:

```
\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark\enspace}\raggedright#1}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=12pt,ignorehead,ignorefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[style=sbl,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,minnames=1,backend=biber,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter,doi=false,url=true]{biblatex}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%
%%footnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark\enspace}\raggedright#1}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother
\setlength{\footnotesep}{24pt}

\begin{document}
    
This is a sample text with a sample footnote.\footnote{This is the footnote text. I would like a space between the footnote marker and the footnote text.}

This is a sample text with a sample footnote.\footnote{This another  footnote text. I would like a space between the  marker and the footnote text.}
    
\end{document}
```

For longer texts I propose to use

```
%%footnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\noindent\makebox[0.7in][r]{\@makefnmark\enspace}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-0.7in}{\raggedright#1}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother
```

[image: c]